# member function of an object of class map

Tags: c++, dictionary

I somehow not sure what is wrong with call to insert for the object "history" where history is of type map. I have checked that there should be an insert function for a map object where the insert function would take in a pair as an argument. However I keep getting the error of

```
#include <map>
using namespace std;
class Solution {
public:
    ListNode *detectCycle(ListNode *head) {
        std::map<ListNode, int> history; \\ so here history is created to be an object of type map
        
        ListNode *current = head;
        
        if(head == NULL) {
            return nullptr;
        } else {
            while(current->next) {
                history.insert(make_pair(current, current->val)); \\ this line has the error of no matching member function for call to "insert"

                if(history.count(current->next)) {
                    return current->next;
                }
            }
        }
        return nullptr;
    }
};
```

could someone points out what is wrong here? or maybe my understanding in the c++ map class?

sorry I am pretty new to c++ and my uses of c++ terminology might not even be right.

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::map<ListNode, int> history;
```

This map's key is a `ListNode`.

```
ListNode *current = head;
```

`current` is a `ListNode *`, a pointer to a `ListNode`.

```
history.insert(make_pair(current, current->val));
```

This attempts to insert a `ListNode *` key into a map whose key is a `ListNode`. This is ill-formed. If a map's key is an `int`, an inserted key must be an `int`. If the map's key is a `ListNode` the inserted key must be a `ListNode`. If the map's key is a `ListNode *` the inserted key must be a `ListNode *`.

Either your map's key is wrong, or your `insert()` call is wrong.

P.S. You appear to be using an outdated C++ textbook to learn C++, or an old C++ compiler that does not implement the current C++ standard. Modern C++ uses a cleaner "uniform initialization" syntax with `insert()` instead of `std::make_pair`. You should see if you can find a more recent textbook and/or compiler, that support modern C++.